# Is there a way to declare variables in list creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, declaration

I'd like to create and assign new String variables when I create my list. I'd like to do something like:

```
l = [first = "first", second = "second"]
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Don't you want a dictionary instead?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this? Assigning in separate statements is perfectly fine and being obsessed with one-liners usually leads to code that is hard to read and understand.

Comment: Not clean from your question, but suggest you read [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is not allowed. Instead you can do the following (You can name it whatever you like, in-place unpacking, iterable unpacking, etc.):

```
first, second = ["first", "second"]
```

However, very similar to what you want to do you can create a dictionary as following which also seems more efficient and Pythonic for your goal here.

```
In [1]: d = dict(first_k = "first", second_k = "second")

In [2]: d['first_k']
Out[2]: 'first'

In [3]: d.keys()
Out[3]: dict_keys(['first_k', 'second_k'])

In [4]: d.values()
Out[4]: dict_values(['first', 'second'])
```

Comment: You can complete the first example: l=first, second = ["first", "second"]

Answer (score 0):

While the syntax above is impossible, you can simply split up the variable assignment and list creation.

```
first, second = "first", "second"
l = [first, second]
```